Format Non-System Drives with ext4+casefold
I'm fairly new to Linux, and just switched over from Windows to Xubuntu 24.04. I have a HDD dedicated to gaming as well as an SSD dedicated to gaming. They are now both formatted in ext4.
Now, however, Games seem to run terribly on these drives--much worse than they did on Windows, but I don't know if that's because of Steam, or Proton, or Linux, or drivers, or what.
Nevertheless, I have read that ext4+casefold is best for Steam on Linux. I've been Googling since yesterday and can't figure out how to do it. Could somebody help me figure out how to enable casefold on these two non-system, gaming-only drives?

I doubt that casefolding will give you better performance. About casfolding you may read this article.

@mook765 - Okay. Thanks.

Enable the filesystem-wide casefold feature, would be somewhat problematic since not all kernels support it. If we enable it in the installer and then someone switches to a different kernel, they might not be able to load their filesystem.
To change the file system of a disk, where all data will be lost, simply, with the disk unmounted in a terminal, execute:
      sudo gparted

In gparted, select the drive you want to format, delete the partition table if it exists, create a new partition table, and then a partition on ext4 file system, once you are sure what you want to do, apply the changes.
Once the disk is mounted, to be able to write and erase it, assuming it is mounted in /media/user/discoxxx, you should execute in a terminal:
     sudo chmod -Rf 666 /media/user/discoxxx


Thanks for trying to help. If I'm understanding correctly, this doesn't give casefold. Is that correct? I've already reformatted the two drives as ext4 (using the pre-installed app, Disks). Now I'm just trying to get casefold going on them.

Please use edit and update the question with the fact you have formatted the drives. As a comment it might get missed.

@David - Done, mate.

sudo umount /dev/sdxx  --  sudo mkfs -t ext4 -O casefold /dev/sdxx
